# django is showing validation errors on its own error page

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-validation

For form validation I need to send error messages, for that I am using validation error but instead of sending errors to template its showing validation error on its error page, you can see image.
[image: This is what I am getting]

In my views

```
    def form_valid(self, form):
    user = get_current_user(self.request)
    review = self.request.POST.get('review')
    user_profile = get_object_or_404(UserProfileModel, display_username=self.kwargs['display_username'])
    ratings = get_object_or_404(Rating,user_profile_model=user_profile)
    try:
        usr_rating = UserRating.objects.get(rating=ratings, user = user)
    except UserRating.DoesNotExist:
        usr_rating = None
    if usr_rating:
        usr_rating.review = review
        usr_rating.save()
    else:
        raise forms.ValidationError('Please rate first')
    return super(UserProfileView,self).form_valid(form)
```

In my template

```
  {% if not form.is_valid %}
      {% for error in form.errors %}
          error
      {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
```

I am unable to figure out the problem or I am confused to use form validation, please help me out.

Comment: You really shouldn't be doing this validation in `form_valid` - that is for when the form is *already* valid. Indeed, you shouldn't do it in the view at all, but in the form itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django will not handle errors raised on view level as form error. Instead of raise error you need to add form error using [`add_error`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.add_error) method. You can override `get_form` method for this:

```
def get_form(self, form_class=None):
    form = super().get_form(form_class)
    if self.request.method == 'POST':
        user = get_current_user(self.request)
        review = self.request.POST.get('review')
        user_profile = get_object_or_404(UserProfileModel, display_username=self.kwargs['display_username'])
        ratings = get_object_or_404(Rating,user_profile_model=user_profile)
        try:
            usr_rating = UserRating.objects.get(rating=ratings, user = user)
        except UserRating.DoesNotExist:
            usr_rating = None
        if usr_rating:
            usr_rating.review = review
            usr_rating.save()
        else:
            form.add_error(None, 'Please rate first')
    return form
```

This will add `non_feild_errors`:

```
{% if form.non_field_errors %}
    {{ form.non_field_errors }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks sir but its showing me this error - 'ReviewForm' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'

Comment: @PankajSharma try to add request method validation. See updates.

Comment: You are not triggering the cleaning and validation of the form, this is made by calling the form.is_valid() method, that's why you have no cleaned data.

Comment: ohh, thanks a lot it worked , check if you could help me out in this also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50822957/django-authenticate-user-from-more-then-one-template